# Angular material illegal state build error

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have checked my code. I uninstalled Material and CDK and reinstalled. I am still getting this error on BUILD.

> ERROR in : Illegal state: Could not load the summary for directive MatToolbar in C:/Users/Floor 15/Code/Angular-design/node_modules/@angular/Material/toolbar/typings/index.d.ts.

When I checked the export /typings/index.d.ts there is code,

```
* from './public-api';
```

Which calls

```
export * from './toolbar-module';
export * from './toolbar';
```

Came across an old post that said that removing the `rootDir` property of `tsconfig.app.json` solved the issue.

The only directory showing for me is `"outDir": "../out-tsc/app"`

Removing this still produced the same error. Only thing I can think of now is removing toolbar element to see I get the same error.

Has anyone experienced this error before?

Comment: Can you setup minimal reproduction and put it on github so that we can investigate?

Comment: It's a pretty big build let me see if I can duplicated it on a smaller scale, will take me a little time. .

Comment: Finally got a stripped version pushed. https://github.com/GreatElk/angularmat.git

Comment: In checking the ""@angular/material/toolbar/package.json" the first line ""name": "@angular/material/toolbar"," I get the error, 
"String does not match the pattern of "^(?:@[a-z0-9-~][a-z0-9-._~]*/)?[a-z0-9-~][a-z0-9-._~]*$".

Comment: It seems I'm able to build the project using "ng b --prod --aot=false --build-optimizer=false"